# Matrix calculus for exponential of determinant and trace of exponential

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I want to solve the $\Lambda$ from the following equation.
$\frac{\partial \det(\Lambda)^{C_{1}} e^{C_{2} tr(w^{-1}\Lambda+\Lambda S)}}{\partial \Lambda} = 0$
where $C_{1}, C_{2}$ is some constant and $\Lambda$, $w^{-1}$, $S$ are all $2x2$ matrix.

I have read the [matrix calculus on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities).

1. I acknowledge it is a scalar by matrix. And I want to use the denominator layout.
2. I write it to  $\frac{\partial{\det(\Lambda)^{C_{1}}}}{\partial{\Lambda}} e^{C_{2}tr(w^{-1}\Lambda+\Lambda S)} + \det(\Lambda)^{C_{1}}\frac{\partial{e^{C_{2} tr(w^{-1}\Lambda+\Lambda S)}}}{\partial{\Lambda}}$
3. I want to calculus the two partial derivate respectively. But I cannot find the identity matrix about $\frac{\det(\Lambda)^{C_{1}}}{\partial{\Lambda}}$, I only find the $\frac{\det(\Lambda^{C_{1}})}{\partial{\Lambda}}$.
4. I cannot find any identity matrix about $\frac{\partial{e^{C_{2} tr(w^{-1}\Lambda+\Lambda S)}}}{\partial{\Lambda}}$.

Please give me some resources for the identity matrix or how to solve it.(I know the calculus but is unfamiliar to matrix calculus. I had solved it when I written it to one dimension equation but it is too demanding)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$\eqalign{
 A &= \Lambda \cr
 b &= C_1 \cr
 c &= C_2 \cr
 e &= \exp\big(C_2\,{\rm tr}(w^{-1}A+AS)\big) \cr
 t &= \det(A) \cr
}$$
Then write the objective function and find its differential 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= et^b \cr
df &= ebt^{b-1}\,dt + t^b\,de \cr
   &= ebt^b\,(\frac{dt}{t}) + t^b\,ce\,d\,{\rm tr}(w^{-1}A+AS) \cr
   &= ebt^b\,d\log(t)) + t^b\,ce\,d{\rm tr}(w^{-1}A+AS) \cr
}$$
If $A$ is non-singular then Jacobi tells us that  $$\log(\det(A))={\rm tr}(\log(A))$$
Substituting this result, we get
$$\eqalign{
 \Big(\frac{1}{et^b}\Big)df &= b\,d{\rm tr}(\log(A)) + c\,d{\rm tr}(w^{-1}A+AS) \cr
  &= b\,A^{-T}:dA + c\,(w^{-1}+S):dA \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial A} &= et^b\Big(b\,A^{-T} + c\,(w^{-1}+S)\Big) \cr
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero and solving for $A$ yields
$$\eqalign{
  b\,A^{-T} &= -c\,(w^{-1}+S) \cr
  A &= -\frac{b}{c}\,(w^{-1}+S)^{-T} \cr
}$$